# How to get the HTML from dataframe without writing to a file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have a large pandas Dataframe

```
df = pd.read_csv("temp.csv")
```

Now I want get the html representation of this dataframe but in memory, and not by writing to a file.

Is there a thing like following

```
html_object=df.to_html()
```

Writing html is incredibly slow.

Comment: Add the sample dataset here..

Comment: Isn't this exactly what you need? `html_object=df.to_html()` or am I miss-understanding it

Comment: Oh, I don't know why I thought to_html writes to a html file. The writing part is usually slow.

Comment: to_html _can_ write to a file, but it returns a string if no buffer or output file is passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes there is](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html#pandas-dataframe-to-html) just use the code you wrote.

```
html_object=df.to_html()
```

Comment: You may consider updating that doc link to the current docs [DataFame.to_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html#pandas-dataframe-to-html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there literally is [`df.to_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html). By default, this will return a string.